# QuickBooks WebConnector authentication fails: "unexpected element (uri:"", local:"strUserName")"

Tags: soap, jax-ws, quickbooks

I'm trying to integrate a Java web application running under JBoss with QuickBooks Desktop and I'm using WebConnector for this purpose. 
I also use JAX-WS for web service implementation in Java.
After a number of solved issues I have faced the one I've stuck: namely while WebConnector is trying to call authenticate method, JBoss throws the following exception:

```
[SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"strUserName"). Expected elements are <{http://developer.intuit.com/}strPassword>,<{http://developer.intuit.com/}strUserName>
```

and

```
[SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"strVersion"). Expected elements are <{http://developer.intuit.com/}strVersion>
```

**Interface:**

```
@WebService(name = "QBWebConnectorService", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/")
public interface QBWebConnectorService {

    @WebMethod
    public String serverVersion(
        @WebParam(name = "strVersion", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/")
        String strVersion);    

    @WebMethod
    public String clientVersion(
        @WebParam(name = "strVersion", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/")
        String strVersion);

    @WebMethod   
    public ArrayOfString authenticate(
            @WebParam(name = "strUserName", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/")
            String strUserName,
            @WebParam(name = "strPassword", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/")
            String strPassword);
...
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@WebService(serviceName = "QBWebConnectorService", targetNamespace = "http://developer.intuit.com/", portName = "QBWebConnector", name = "QBWebConnector", endpointInterface = "com.example.myapp.ws.QBWebConnectorService")
public class QBWebConnector implements QBWebConnectorService {

    @Override
    public ArrayOfString authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword) {
        ArrayOfString arr = new ArrayOfString();
        arr.string = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.string.add("{57F3B8B1-86F1-4fcc-B1EE-566DE1813D20}");
        arr.string.add(""); //To use the currently open company, specify an empty string
        return arr;     
    }
...
}
```

Calls to serverVersion() and clientVersion() are executed as expected with no errors. And call to authenticate() has this issue with the namespace. But I just can't figure out why. 
Can anybody provide some ideas? Thanks...

Comment: I would add a proxy tool (such as tcpmon) in between QBWC and your JBoss service provider.  Point QBWC at the proxy and have the proxy forward ws traffic to the JBoss service provider app.  Inspect the traffic and post the offending XML if necessary.  Also compare the WSDL used in your service provider to [this one](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl); perhaps there is a subtle difference.

Comment: The issue has been finally solved by changing package name to com.intuit.developer and by adding some annotations to the authenticate method following the examples from [here](https://github.com/phstc/JavaQuickBooksWebConnector)